# How can I convert int to boolean in entityframework core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here are two tables,one named `State`, the other named `WorkingOn`.

```
workers_name    state
aaa             onduty
bbb             offduty
ccc             onduty
ddd             onduty
```

```
workers_name    working_on
aaa             projectA
aaa             projectB
aaa             projectC
bbb             projectB
bbb             projectC
```

Now I need to show whether the worker on duty is busy or free in front-end. The table `WorkingOn` needs to record the detail of what the workers are working on that I can't change it.

Therefore, I have set the boolean `Busy` to true while there is a work(no matter how many projects the worker is working on) for the worker and set the boolean `Busy` to false while there is no work for the worker.

In my opinion, maybe I should get the counts of the project what workers are working on and then convert the count to a boolean. In spite of this works in theory, I consider it will wasting so much performance for it needs to search all the count of the project what workers are working on. There will be millions of data in the table `WorkingOn` that I have to think about this.

Here is the model what the Entity framework needs to convert to:

```
public class WorkerStatus
{
   public string workers_name{get;set;}
   public boolean busy{get;set;}
}
```

And here is the model of the database:

```
public class TestDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public virtual DbSet<statemodel> state { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<workingonmodel> workingon { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=123.db");
            }
            public TestDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
            {

            }

        protected TestDBContext()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<statemodel>().HasNoKey();
            builder.Entity<workingonmodel>().HasNoKey();
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

```
public class statemodel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class workingonmodel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string working { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this way:

```
var workerInQuestion = state.Select(X => new
            {
                name = X.name,
                busy = workingon.Any(Y => Y.name == X.name)
            }) ;
```

All works well now.